# infinite while loop, while AsyncTask is not finish

Tags: java, android, loops, android-asynctask, splash-screen

I have a SplashScreen Activity which call Asynctask Class to get information in internet.

I want to wait while my Asynctask is not finish (time during on internet speed connection)

My activity:

```java
public static boolean test = true;

[...]

final Liste en_ce_moment = new Liste("En ce moment au cinéma", nowMovie);
mesListes.add(en_ce_moment);

//call my Asynctask file 
fetchNowMovie process = new fetchNowMovie();
process.execute();

while(test)
{

}

Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
```

My Asynctask:

```java
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

        SplashScreenActivity.test = false;

        SplashScreenActivity.nowMovie.clear();
        SplashScreenActivity.nowMovie.addAll(list);

    }
```

Logically, the boolean became false in `onPostExecute` so the while loop stop and the intent have to start but the while loop never stop...

Comment: Well, `test` is set to **true**, so you have `while(true) { }`. What were you expecting? :|

Comment: Maybe the while is going too fast, try putting a little sleep there

Comment: I try to put ```SystemClock.sleep(1000);``` in while loop but nothing change @RicardoA.

Comment: `I want to wait while my Asynctask is not finish (time during on internet speed connection)`

Why are you doing something asynchronously if it's not asynchronous? You're doing it wrong. If you _really_ want to do this, check the status of the task. See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask#getStatus()

Comment: @jmart SplashScreenActivity is the activity which a lunch in first in the app, it call my asynctask, and after that, MainActivity is started. the code on my question is in SplashScreenActivity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's do what you want to do in a safe way by using simple `interface` logic:

So we added our simple `interface` and we re-define your `MyAsnycTask` class's `constructor` like so:

```java
public class MyAsnycTask extends AsyncTask
{

    OnTaskFinished listener;

    // Our simple interface
    public interface OnTaskFinished {
        void TimeToNextActivity();
    }

    // Your MyAsnycTask class constructor
    public MyAsnycTask(OnTaskFinished l) {
        listener = l;
    }

    . . .
```

As a last line of code in `onPostExecute()`, we're done whatever we're doing. So tell this via our `listener`:

```java
listener.TimeToNextActivity();
```

To use our `interface` that we added earlier, your `Activity` must `implements` it. So we implements it. And in implemented method, we go to next `Activity` with `Intent`:

```java
public class MyActivity extends Activity
implements MyAsnycTask.OnTaskFinished
{

    @Override
    public void TimeToNextActivity()
    {
        // Here go to next activity
        Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);

    }
```

As we modified our `MyAsnycTask` class's `constructor`, we must initialize it like this:

```java
MyAsnycTask process = new MyAsnycTask(this);
process.execute();
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a problem hiding inside another problem, but to get through the first-level issue you could try using `CountDownLatch` instead of a static boolean:

```
CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
fetchNowMovie process = new fetchNowMovie(latch);
process.execute();

latch.await();

Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
```

You'll have to accept the latch as part of your AsyncTask's constructor:

```
private final CountDownLatch latch;

public fetchNowMovie(CountDownLatch latch) {
    this.latch = latch;
}

// ...

protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
    super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

    latch.countDown();

    SplashScreenActivity.nowMovie.clear();
    SplashScreenActivity.nowMovie.addAll(list);
}
```

Comment: Note that this will presumably block your UI thread for the duration of the AsyncTask, making it quite likely that you'll get an "Application Not Responding" popup. You probably want to truly allow asynchronous execution of the task, and have `onPostExecute()` notify the activity that it is ready to proceed, rather than trying to block with a boolean or CountDownLatch.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use very simple library:
https://github.com/Arasthel/AsyncJobLibrary

Just start your Splash activity:

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, SplashScreenActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
```

In "onCreate" method of Splash activity do, what you need in background and after mission complete, do on main thread (update list):

```
AsyncJob.doInBackground(new AsyncJob.OnBackgroundJob() {
    @Override
    public void doOnBackground() {

        //load from local DB or http-request:
        List<Movie> movieList = fetchNowMovie();
        //You can convert movieList to Json string, for example and save in SharedPreferences. Or you can use local DB for saving new movies.

        // Send the result to the UI thread and show it
        AsyncJob.doOnMainThread(new AsyncJob.OnMainThreadJob() {
            @Override
            public void doInUIThread() {
                Intent i = new Intent(splashScreenContext, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);  
                //load movies from shared preferences or local Database in MainActivity (onCreate)                 
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Connect library (build.gradle in app-project directory):

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'com.arasthel:asyncjob-library:1.0.3'
    ...
}
```